# Current date is failing to format in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the jquery datepicker, and when today's date is selected, it's failing to convert to  the format I need for a database query.

The datepicker date format is 'm-d-Y', so today appears as 09-16-2013.
This part is working, and the datepicker correctly displays today's date as the default selection.

However, I need to use 'Y-m-d' format to query the database.  This works fine when the date is less than today.  But for today, it's failing and I'm getting 1969-12-31.

```
echo $enddt;
```

displays: 09-16-2013

I have tried:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtodate($enddt));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtodate($enddt));
```

and neither works.
How do I format $enddt so it displays 2013-09-16 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is actually [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), not `strtodate()`:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Since you have the date string separated by dashes, we'll need to convert it into slashes first to make `strtotime()` recognize the format as `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
$enddt = '09-16-2013';
$enddt = str_replace('-', '/', $enddt);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($enddt));
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/fq0kjsbH)

Answer (score 2):

```
$enddt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '09-16-2013');
echo $enddt->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ERtYOo)